# How to calculate interest payments without EBIT

Tags: calculation, income-statement

is there a way to calculate interest payments without EBIT. For example if I am searching for Apple Inc. in google finance I don't have Interest Payments in the income statement, there is no EBIT either. How can I calculate it then ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual financial statements should always be referenced first before opening or closing a position.

For US companies, they are freely available on EDGAR.  Annual reports are called 10-Ks, and quarterly reports are called 10-Qs.

YHOO and GOOG do a great job of posting financials that are quickly available, but money.msn has the best.  These should be starting point, quick references.  As you can see, they may all have the same strange accounting.

Sometimes, it's difficult to find the information one seeks in the consolidated financial statements as in this case, so searching through the filing is necessary.

The notes can be helpful, but `Ctrl-F` seems to do everything I need when I want something in a report.

In AAPL's case, the **Interest expense** can be found in [**Note 3**](http://yahoo.brand.edgar-online.com/displayfilinginfo.aspx?FilingID=9731522-24979-87317&type=sect&dcn=0001193125-14-024487).

Comment: So I can't calculate it with the statements from google finance. I have to find another source for the statements, did I get it properly?